# The Select Method must return one of "IQueryable" or "IEnumerable"

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

After I have upgraded to Microsoft OWIN Authentication/OpenAuth2 from Dotnet.OpenAuth I get this error when I try to access the login page.

> The Select Method must return one of "IQueryable" or "IEnumerable" or "Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.ProviderDetails" when ItemType is set to "Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.ProviderDetails".

Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET C#

What can cause this error?

This is the line which throws the error from OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> GetProviderNames()
    {
        return Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes().Select(t => t.AuthenticationType);
    }
```

This is the **OpenAuthProvider.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OpenAuthProviders.ascx.cs" Inherits="QuoteHD.Account.OpenAuthProviders" %>

<fieldset class="open-auth-providers">
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="providerDetails" ItemType="Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.ProviderDetails"
        SelectMethod="GetProviderNames" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <button type="submit" class="socialLoginButton <%#: Item.ProviderName %>" name="provider" value="<%#: Item.ProviderName %>"
                title="Log in using your <%#: Item.ProviderDisplayName %> account.">
                <%#: Item.ProviderDisplayName %>
            </button>
            <br /><br />
        </ItemTemplate>

        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <div class="message-info">
                <p>There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252803">this article</a> for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.</p>
            </div>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @maria - show ur code!

Comment: You can show with the line that throws the exception as a start.

Comment: I have added the line which causes the error.

Comment: Can we see the designer code for your (presumably) ASPX page? I think that's where the actual error is.

Comment: I have added the ASCX page